# Django - passing variable from function view into html template

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Good afternoon, I have a problem and I can't figure it out how to do it. I am using a third party api for data, I am storing it into `metar` variable and passing it as argument. However it is not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Views.py

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
# Create your views here.
class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

def index(request, template_name="index.html"):
    headers = {
  'Authorization': 'my_private_api'
    }
    args={}
    request = Request('https://avwx.rest/api/metar/KJFK', headers=headers)
    response_body = urlopen(request).read()
    args['metar'] = response_body
    return TemplateResponse(request,template_name,args)
```

index.html

```
{%block content %}
<div>
   <h1>Metary</h1>
   <p>{{ metar }}</p>
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from dashboard.views import DashboardView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', DashboardView.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am going to answer your question in terms of django, you will have to figure out how to get request from external api from their docs.

According to django docs: A [TemplateView's Method Flowchart is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview)

1. setup()
2. dispatch()
3. http_method_not_allowed()
4. get_context_data()

now you are using

```
def index(request, template_name="index.html"):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'my_private_api'}
    args={}
    request = Request('https://avwx.rest/api/metar/KJFK', headers=headers)
    response_body = urlopen(request).read()
    args['metar'] = response_body
    return TemplateResponse(request,template_name,args)
```

which is not going to work beacuse this `def index(...` is not executed at all. so you have nothing in your context `metar`

so changing your code to:

```
class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        #headers = {'Authorization': 'my_private_api'}
        #request = Request('https://avwx.rest/api/metar/KJFK',headers=headers)
        #response_body = urlopen(request).read()

        context['metar'] = 'some information'
        return context
```

will give you `metar` as `'some information'` in your template.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the render function to simplify this.

e.g.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request, template_name="index.html"):
    return render(request, template_name, {'metar': 'Hello world'})
```

Comment: i made it but still when i pass {{metar}} in index.html i get nothing.

Comment: Your 'def index' view isn't in your `urlpatterns`? So it's using `DashboardView` instead. Try and add it there instead of `DashboardView`.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, I got to know that you have **two views** as `DashboardView` which is a template view and another `index` which is function based view (and you have configured it improperly). In Urls you have configured `DashboardView` as your view handler and your actual api code lies in `index` that's why it was not working. Following solution is based on function based view, this might help.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

def index(request):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'my_private_api'}
    request = Request('https://avwx.rest/api/metar/KJFK', headers=headers)
    response_body = urlopen(request).read()
    context = {
    'metar':response_body
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context=context)
```

template.html

```
{%block content %}
<div>
   <h1>Metary</h1>
   <p>{{ metar }}</p>
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index ),
]
```

Comment: I have not tested it as it contain api calls, but if you get any errors let me know.